# Getting error while adding action cable on server with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I have created appearance and chat channels and they are working fine at my local machine ie. (localhost:3000) but after merging code on production, the server stops working after some time and returning me an error like:

This website is under heavy load (queue full)

Please help me on how to smoothly run the action cable on the server.

Comment: The information you provided is not enough to help you here. Are there any stacktraces? Did you setup Redis? Where did you deploy your application? Without being specific the community will not be able to help or will do so out of mere assumptions.

Comment: Hi  theterminalguy,
Please check the details:

Hosting : AWS
Server: Apache server with Passenger

Redis server is not set up yet